# Huggingface Trainer throws an AttributeError:'Namespace' object has no attribute 'get_process_log_level

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to run Trainer from Hugging face(pytorch) with arguments parser. My code looks like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = HfArgumentParser(TrainingArguments)
    parser.add_argument('--model_name_or_path', type=str, required=True)
    .
    .
    .   
    .


    training_args = parser.parse_args()

    print('args', training_args)

    os.makedirs(training_args.output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    random.seed(training_args.seed)
    
    set_seed(training_args.seed)

    dataset_train = ...

    .
    .
    .


    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataloader,
        eval_dataset=val_dataloader)

    trainer.train()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 250, in <module>
    eval_dataset=val_dataloader)
    File "C:\User\transformer\lib\site- 
    packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 316, in __init__
    log_level = args.get_process_log_level()
    AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'get_process_log_level
```

Any idea about this error and how to solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check that this works for you:

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments

args = TrainingArguments(output_dir='./')
args.get_process_log_level()
```

[out]:

```
20
```

If it doesn't then most probably the version of `transformers` you have on `C:\User\transformer\lib\site-packages\transformers` doesn't match the Trainer script you have. Then try to upgrade your transformers version `pip install -U transformers`.

---

If you get the `20` output but when you run your script you're getting the error, then most probably the version of your transformers is from a previous version that doesn't have the `get_process_log_level()` in the `TrainingArguments` as a property.

Add this line at the top of your code and check that the

```
import sys; print(sys.executable)
```

you'll get something like

[out]:

```
C://something/somewhere/bin/python
```

and with that do this to upgrade the library to the right site-package location and python binary

```
C://something/somewhere/bin/python -m pip install -U transformers
```

After upgrading the script should run.

Comment: It actually worked, I got 20 as an output. What could be the problem ?

Comment: The version of your `transformers` is from a previous version that doesn't have the `get_process_log_level()` in the TrainingArguments as a property. After upgrading your transformer version, did your script/code run properly?

Comment: Add this line at the top of your code and check that the `import sys; print(sys.executable)`, then you'll get something like `C://something/somewhere/bin/python`, and with that do `C://something/somewhere/bin/python -m pip install -U transformers`

Comment: Great! May the neurons be in your favor!