# How to convert TrainingArguments object into a json file?

Tags: python, json, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I want to convert an object of TrainingArguments into a json file and load json when training model because I think it didn't look better in main function and hard to check all parameters in TrainingArguments, for example,

```
import json
import dataclasses
from transformers import TrainingArguments

class EnhancedJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if dataclasses.is_dataclass(obj):
            return dataclasses.asdict(obj)
        #return super().default(obj)
    
def save_json(json_path, file_args): 
    file_str = json.dumps(file_args, cls=EnhancedJSONEncoder)
    file_json = json.loads(file_str) 
    with open(json_path, "w") as f:
        json.dump(file_json, f, indent=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir = "train_model",
        do_eval=True,
        do_predict=False,
        do_train=True,
        eval_steps=20,
        save_steps=-1,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
        per_device_train_batch_size=4,
        max_steps=1000,
        learning_rate=7e-05,
        evaluation_strategy="steps",
        dataloader_num_workers=1,
        )
    training_args._n_gpu = 1
    save_json("training_args.json",training_args)
```

Thus, firstly, I save `training_args` to a json file, if I want to use parameters in `training_args` I directly import from json file,
from types import SimpleNamespace

```
with open("training_args.json", 'r') as f:
    training_json = json.load(f)
training_args = SimpleNamespace(**training_json)
```

It can correctly show `training_args.output_dir`,`training_args.do_train`

However, when I run

```
trainer = transformers.Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset if training_args.do_train else None,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset if training_args.do_eval else None,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    )
```

it shows error, `'types.SimpleNamespace' object has no attribute 'get_process_log_level'`

If I print TrainingArguments.get_process_log_level(), it shows

<bound method TrainingArguments.get_process_log_level of TrainingArguments(
_n_gpu=1,
adafactor=False, #etc..
)

Comment: I see someone face similar problem in 75595065, and the solution is updating transformers, my transf version is 4.12.5, the problem is it can works in this old version by using `training_args = TrainingArguments()` while importing from json file showing this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `.to_json_string()` function in `TrainingArguments`.

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir = "train_model",
    do_eval=True,
    do_predict=False,
    do_train=True,
    eval_steps=20,
    save_steps=-1,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    max_steps=1000,
    learning_rate=7e-05,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    dataloader_num_workers=1,
    )

training_args.to_json_string()
```

[out]:

```
{
  "output_dir": "train_model",
  "overwrite_output_dir": false,
  "do_train": true,
  "do_eval": true,
  "do_predict": false,
  "evaluation_strategy": "steps",
  "prediction_loss_only": false,
  "per_device_train_batch_size": 4,
  "per_device_eval_batch_size": 8,
  "per_gpu_train_batch_size": null,
  "per_gpu_eval_batch_size": null,
  "gradient_accumulation_steps": 1,
  "eval_accumulation_steps": null,
  ...
}
```

Then you can dump it out to json file and load the json file, e.g.

```
import json

with open('args.json', 'w') as fout:
  fout.write(training_args.to_json_string())

with open('args.json') as fin:
  args_json = json.load(fin)
```

To load the the JSON file back into a `TrainingArguments` object.

```
from transformers import HfArgumentParser, TrainingArguments

parser = HfArgumentParser(TrainingArguments)
training_args, = parser.parse_json_file(json_file='args.json')

print(type(training_args))
print(training_args)
```

[out]:

```
<class 'transformers.training_args.TrainingArguments'>

TrainingArguments(
  _n_gpu=0,
  adafactor=False,
  adam_beta1=0.9,
  adam_beta2=0.999,
  adam_epsilon=1e-08,
  ...
)
```

---

As for the `object has no attribute 'get_process_log_level'` error, try updating your tranformers version, see also [Huggingface Trainer throws an AttributeError:'Namespace' object has no attribute 'get_process_log_level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75595065/huggingface-trainer-throws-an-attributeerrornamespace-object-has-no-attribute/75595490#75595490)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply again, when I run `training_args, = parser.parse_json_file(json_file='args.json') it shows `Exception has occurred: KeyError
-1` ,why?
`

Comment: Check for typos, see that you have `training_args, = ...` instead of `training_args = ...`. It sort of a weird thing cos usually the HFArgument Parser takes in a tuple of arguments not just the training args.

Comment: that's true, but I have converted `model_args`, `data_arg`(written by @dataclass directly) to json file, I was wondering if `TrainingArguments` has some methods that can `training_args =  TrainingArguments.import_from_json_file("data/train.json")`

Comment: Besides, if I want to input in code not cmd, how should I rewrite this `model_args, data_args, training_args = parser.parse_json_file(json_file=os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]))`, (if model.json/data.json/train.json)

Comment: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/question-answering/run_qa.py#L222 =)